# Python return type annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, annotations

When declaring a function, should we use return annotations?

```
def generate_nine() -> int:
    return 9
```

Or can we simply put something like this:

```
def generate_nine():
    return 9
```

Comment: This is very much a matter of opinion. If you like the style and like the extra help IDEs give you when you use them, go for it. If your organization requires them, then yeah. I think annotations are python's jump the shark moment. What happened to a decent doc string? Not that I'm opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You should write return type annotation for writing cleaner code. It's been said that return type annotation enhanced code readability. Consider an example

For example:

```
   def get_data(a):
       return a ** 2
```

It is not easier for anyone, what is the expected return type.
If the incoming data is `float`, the function will return `float`. 
If the function receive `int` value, it will return `int`. So even it is not easier to read.

So for better understanding it is being recommended to write both arguments type and return type while writing. See the below example:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

In the function greeting, the argument name is expected to be of type `str` and the return type `str`. Subtypes are accepted as arguments. The compiler will raise an error if it is not expecting a string value.

The code is much clear and understandable compare to the previous one. So to summarize, for writing cleaner code we should add return type annotation. Please see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) docs for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

In more detail, Python 2.x has docstrings, which allow you to attach a metadata string to various types of object. This is amazingly handy, so Python 3 extends the feature by allowing you to attach metadata to functions describing their parameters and return values.

There's no preconceived use case, but the PEP suggests several. One very handy one is to allow you to annotate parameters with their expected types; it would then be easy to write a decorator that verifies the annotations or coerces the arguments to the right type. Another is to allow parameter-specific documentation instead of encoding it into the docstring.

[DOCS](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)